# No known class method for selector 'name'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

[image]I have two files, one that's called CodeInjection.m with the content like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Someheaderfile.h"


@interface CodeInjection: NSObject
@end

@implementation CodeInjection

static void __attribute__((constructor)) initialize(void){
    NSLog(@"==== Code Injection in Action====");
    [[CodeInjectionSwift shared] performTask];
}

@end
```

Then I have a CodeInjectionSwift.swift file with content

```
import Foundation
import NetworkInterceptor

@objc class CodeInjectionSwift: NSObject {
    @objc public static let shared = CodeInjectionSwift()

    override private init(){}

    @objc func performTask(){
        let requestSniffers: [RequestSniffer] = [
            RequestSniffer(requestEvaluator: AnyHttpRequestEvaluator(), handlers: [
                SniffableRequestHandlerRegistrable.console(logginMode: .nslog).requestHandler()
                ])
        ]

        let requestRedirectors: [RequestRedirector] = [
            RequestRedirector(requestEvaluator: DomainHttpRequestEvaluator(domain: "www.antennahouse.com"), redirectableRequestHandler: AlternateUrlRequestRedirector(url: URL(string: "https://www.rhodeshouse.ox.ac.uk/media/1002/sample-pdf-file.pdf")!))
        ]

        let networkConfig = NetworkInterceptorConfig(requestSniffers: requestSniffers,
                                                     requestRedirectors: requestRedirectors)
        NetworkInterceptor.shared.setup(config: networkConfig)
        NetworkInterceptor.shared.startRecording()
    }
}
```

When trying to use "CodeInjectionSwift", I get errors like this

[image]

Comment: What can you see when you examine the generated Swift to OC header "MyModule-Swift.h"  . For that matter why are you not using `#import "MyModule-Swift.h"` in `CodeInjection.m` . Without that you can't see the Swift code parts within an Objective-C file.

Answer (score 0):

Make `@objc func performTask()` public:
`@objc public func performTask()`

Comment: The class needs to be `public` too

Answer (score 0):

My original answer is wrong. I've left it below for context.

In fact the whole problem is that you need to import a special header into your Objective-C class.

```
    #import "TestImportSwift-Swift.h"
```

where `TestImportSwift` is replaced by the name of your project.

---

**Old wrong answer**

`shared` is not a `class` member, it is a `static` member. Unfortunately, Swift doesn't support class variables, only functions, so you could try

```
@objc class CodeInjectionSwift: NSObject {

    static let _shared = CodeInjectionSwift()
    @objc public class func shared() -> CodeInjectionSwift { return _shared }

    // Rest of the class
```

Note that I haven't tried this in a real project.

Comment: Where does this line go? @objc public class func shared() -> CodeInjectionSwift { return _shared }

Comment: @Dilli It's in place of your static declaration of `shared`

Comment: I've made the changes like shown in the post, the initial error hasn't gone. Do anything need to be also changed in the m file? The error is being produced from this line  [[CodeInjectionSwift shared] performTask]; in the CodeInjection.m file.

Comment: @Dilli what do you mean the initial error hasn't gone? Does it still say 'No class method...'?

Comment: @Dilli Have you got a `#import "<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h"` in your Objective-C code?

Comment: Objective-C code file would be the .m file or the .swift file? in the .m file I'm importing the <project_name>.h file however not in the .swift file.

Comment: #import <SpotifyCodeInjection/SpotifyCodeInjection-Swift.h>
I was able to import the file, however the error is still there. The same error.

Comment: @Dilli No. Just do it the same as I did it. I created an Objectivce-C project, added a Swift class to it and it worked. Also, put it in the same `.m` file as you are using the Swift class in.

Comment: @Dilli you still haven't put the right import in there.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nYt5.jpg That's the image, I've added the -Swift.h file.

Comment: @Dilli Not correctly. It's `#import "Project-Swift.h"` not `#import <Project/Project-Swift.h>` where "Project" is the name of **your** project.

Comment: I tried how you initially showed me, however it is not able to import the header file. https://i.imgur.com/eS7UFbg.png

Comment: @Dilli Is the Objecitve-C in the same module as the Swift code? Because it should work if it is. See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c)

Comment: here's the screenshot of the file structure https://i.imgur.com/c5knKZJ.png

Comment: @Dilli Yes, that ought to be working. Maybe do a clean and rebuild from scratch. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: No luck :( tried creating new project aswell. Perhaps something needs to be changed in the build settings?

Comment: @Dilli Try making a scratch Objective-C project and then recreating the class and copy-pasting the code into the new file. See if that works (it's what I did to test my answer).

Comment: Turns out, I cannot import header file like that instead I had to do “import <module_name/module_name-Swift.h” your initial answer actually gave me a right path. I can not import like that in dynamic framework project. It does however work if I created a normal single view project

Comment: @Dilli So you fixed it, great.